# Using mopidy to stream audio to MPoD

Tags: audio, mopidy

I've installed [mopidy](https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/ext/http/) on a clean build of Rasbian Jessie.
I've managed to run it, and get [MPoD](http://www.katoemba.net/makesnosenseatall/mpod/) to connect to it over my local WiFI.
I've configured mopidy to enable the mpd server (hostname = 0.0.0.0 port =6600), and as an HTTP server (hostname = 0.0.0.0 port=6680).

I can see MPoD connecting to it, and I can see the mp3 file stored locally onto my Pi from MPoD.

In MPoD's connection setings I have chosen the On The Go connection mode, and disabled Use Local Cache as recommended in the MPoD help docs.  I've chosen the Pi's IP address (192.168.1.xx) and correct port numbers for both MPD and HTTP.

I think it is trying to play the audio locally from the Pi's headphone jack.  I want it to stream to the MPoD client on my iOS device.

But when I play an audio file in MPoD, the timer increases, but nothing plays from the iOS device.  The server gives a warning:

```
WARNING  GStreamer warning: gst-stream-error-quark: No volume control found (3)
```

What am I missing?

Update: - I think I'm missing two important elements from GStream, but I don't know how to install them?

```
    $ mopidy deps
Executable: /usr/bin/mopidy
Platform: Linux-4.1.17+-armv6l-with-debian-8.0
Python: CPython 2.7.9 from /usr/lib/python2.7
Mopidy: 2.0.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  Pykka>=1.1: 1.2.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  requests>=2.0: 2.4.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  tornado>=2.3: 3.2.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
GStreamer: 1.4.4.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi
  Detailed information: 
    Python wrapper: python-gi 3.14.0
    Relevant elements:
      Found:
        uridecodebin
        souphttpsrc
        appsrc
        alsasink
        osssink
        oss4sink
        pulsesink
        id3demux
        id3v2mux
        lamemp3enc
        mad
        mpegaudioparse
        vorbisdec
        vorbisenc
        vorbisparse
        oggdemux
        oggmux
        oggparse
        flacdec
        flacparse
        shout2send
      Not found:
        flump3dec
        mpg123audiodec
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is trying to play the audio locally from the Pi's headphone jack. I want it to stream to the MPoD client on my iOS device.

Yes, mopidy will play audio locally through the Pi's audio output - be that HDMI or the analog out. Streaming to MPoD is none of mopidy's business. Technically it might be conceivable to create a GStreamer Pipeline with a network sink thus "streaming" mopidy's output to another device - but that is not something that will be working with MPoD (at least to my understanding of MPoD). The clients - such as MPoD - that connect to mopidy via numerous protocolls, e.g. HTTP or MPD, are just a remote graphical frontend to control mopidy - a remote control if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Those two plugins are to decode mpg files. That may very well be the problem. I just installed mopidy today. Twice, and for some reason installing mopidy would leave flump3dec installed incorrectly in my case. I did:

```
sudo apt-get gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
```

And that worked for me. But I did read on a github discussion, that `flump3dec` is old and `mpg123audiodec` was recommended instead. I just did not take the time to find it. You can do a search like this:

```
apt search gstreamer*
```

And possibly find it. Let us know here if you find the name of the package. Either way just a simple `apt-get` with the right package will most likely work